# numba cuda deprecation error : how to update my code?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

Im running a jupyter notebook frome here :
https://github.com/noahgift/nuclear_powered_command_line_tools/blob/master/notebooks/numba-cuda.ipynb

The docs of current numba/cuda is here : https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda-reference/kernel.html#kernel-declaration

Im running this line in numba.cuda in python :

```
from numba import cuda
from numba import *
```

I have a mandel function as follow:

```
@jit
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
  """
    Given the real and imaginary parts of a complex number,
    determine if it is a candidate for membership in the Mandelbrot
    set given a fixed number of iterations.
  """
  c = complex(x, y)
  z = 0.0j
  for i in range(max_iters):
    z = z*z + c
    if (z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
      return i

  return max_iters
```

I run cuda with

```
mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(func_or_sig=mandel,device=True)
# previously  mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(restype=uint32, argtypes=[f8, f8, uint32], device=True)(mandel)
```

with mandel defined as

```
  @cuda.jit#(argtypes=[f8, f8, f8, f8, uint8[:,:], uint32])
def mandel_kernel(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, image, iters):
  height = image.shape[0]
  width = image.shape[1]

  pixel_size_x = (max_x - min_x) / width
  pixel_size_y = (max_y - min_y) / height

  startX, startY = cuda.grid(2)
  gridX = cuda.gridDim.x * cuda.blockDim.x;
  gridY = cuda.gridDim.y * cuda.blockDim.y;

  for x in range(startX, width, gridX):
    real = min_x + x * pixel_size_x
    for y in range(startY, height, gridY):
      imag = min_y + y * pixel_size_y 
      image[y, x] = mandel_gpu(real, imag, iters)
```

I get then the following call :

```
gimage = np.zeros((1024, 1536), dtype = np.uint8)
blockdim = (32, 8)
griddim = (32,16)

start = timer()
d_image = cuda.to_device(gimage)
mandel_kernel[griddim, blockdim](-2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, d_image, 20) 
d_image.to_host()
dt = timer() - start

print("Mandelbrot created on GPU in %f s" % dt)

imshow(gimage)
show()
```

I get then the error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/errors.py in new_error_context(fmt_, *args, **kwargs)
    822     try:
--> 823         yield
    824     except NumbaError as e:

33 frames

NotImplementedError: No definition for lowering <built-in method mandel of _dynfunc._Closure object at 0x7efde36f8590>(float64, float64, int64) -> int64


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LoweringError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/errors.py in new_error_context(fmt_, *args, **kwargs)
    835             else:
    836                 tb = None
--> 837             raise newerr.with_traceback(tb)
    838         elif use_new_style_errors():
    839             raise e

LoweringError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
No definition for lowering <built-in method mandel of _dynfunc._Closure object at 0x7efde36f8590>(float64, float64, int64) -> int64

File "<ipython-input-14-82f426a4058e>", line 17:
def mandel_kernel(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, image, iters):
    <source elided>
      imag = min_y + y * pixel_size_y 
      image[y, x] = mandel_gpu(real, imag, iters)
      ^

During: lowering "$160call_function.12 = call $152load_global.8(real, imag, iters, func=$152load_global.8, args=[Var(real, <ipython-input-14-82f426a4058e>:14), Var(imag, <ipython-input-14-82f426a4058e>:16), Var(iters, <ipython-input-14-82f426a4058e>:3)], kws=(), vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None)" at <ipython-input-14-82f426a4058e> (17)
```

I have tried to update the code with the comments stating the updated api doesnt take argtypes and restypes but i still get an error and i have no clues how to correct it...
Thank you
Thanks for your help

Comment: im taking the example from a course and the result in the video was 10 times faster than with onlt jit numba, which was 10 times faster than with nothing

Comment: @Robert Crovella ok thanks for the link. So what i am supposed to do with my argtypes and restype? can i define them elsewhere?

Comment: I ve updated the example code. It comes from here: https://github.com/noahgift/nuclear_powered_command_line_tools

Comment: @user19413311 This is not fair to compare a sequential code running only on 1 core of a CPU with a full GPU device (parallel). It would be much better to compare the GPU version to a parallel CPU version. This means using `parallel=True` and `prange` instead of `range`.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard ok i will think about it, the purpose of my example is to show how paralellisation can improve performances

Comment: Don't try and `@cuda.jit` a function you have already compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a few minutes to review how python decorators work, because this is at the core of your problem.

When you do this:

```
@jit
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
    ...
```

what is happening is this:

```
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
    ...

mandel = jit(mandel)
```

i.e. your original function is replaced by a Numba processed, `jit` compiled version of your original Python code. Plainly the Numba GPU compiler can't compile a previously Numba compiled function, thus the error when you try and compile a device function from that already compiled code.

If you did something like this:

```
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
    ...


mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(mandel, device=True)
mandel = jit(mandel)
```

I suspect the compilation would work correctly (although I haven't tried it, that is up to you).

Comment: I dont think that is the problem, as im keeping the decorators as they were in the original code that worked with a previous version...Also i have tried to remove the decorator whre the code is giving error and it doesnt solve the problem...i get another error function is not subscriptable