# DeprecationError: Deprecated keyword argument `argtypes`. Signatures should be passed as the first positional argument

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, numba

I am use Google Colab pro, my code

```py
def mandel(x, y, max_iters):
  """
    Given the real and imaginary parts of a complex number,
    determine if it is a candidate for membership in the Mandelbrot
    set given a fixed number of iterations.
  """
  c = complex(x, y)
  z = 0.0j
  for i in range(max_iters):
    z = z*z + c
    if (z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag) >= 4:
      return i

  return max_iters
```

and

```py
mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(restype=uint32, argtypes=[f8, f8, uint32], device=True)(mandel)
```

base on source code https://github.com/donhuvy/cloud-data-analysis-at-scale/blob/master/GPU_Programming.ipynb

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DeprecationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-7e6daab3cbbb> in <module>
----> 1 mandel_gpu = cuda.jit(restype=uint32, argtypes=[f8, f8, uint32], device=True)(mandel)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/cuda/decorators.py in jit(func_or_sig, device, inline, link, debug, opt, cache, **kws)
     62     if kws.get('argtypes') is not None:
     63         msg = _msg_deprecated_signature_arg.format('argtypes')
---> 64         raise DeprecationError(msg)
     65     if kws.get('restype') is not None:
     66         msg = _msg_deprecated_signature_arg.format('restype')

DeprecationError: Deprecated keyword argument `argtypes`. Signatures should be passed as the first positional argument.
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Don't use `argtypes`, and pass the value as the first argument instead. That said, deprecations aren't supposed to be errors; it's a *warning* that something will be an error in the future.

Comment: Is it `mandel_gpu = cuda.jit([f8, f8, uint32], device=True)(mandel)` ? Your answer is hard to understand than my problem.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73283597/numba-cuda-deprecation-error-how-to-update-my-code

Answer (score 0):

Recent Numba documentation https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13/CUDAJit.html, suggests to update couple of lines - the way you pass the arguments.

```
mandel_gpu = cuda.jit('f8, f8, uint32', device=True)(mandel)
```

and  in the decorator

```
@cuda.jit('f8, f8, f8, f8, uint8[:,:], uint32')
```

Just tested it, worked
[image]